# What secure RFID standards are there; for high value item inventory?

Tags: digital-signature, rfid

I am wanting to use some RFID devices to help with inventory management of some high value items (paintings).

The paintings are packed in wooden transport cases, awaiting shipment. Periodically we, have some one from security, scan the barcodes on the cases to ensure the correct items are where they are supposed to be.

However it turns out it is trivial to peel a barcode off one case and put it on another...

I am looking to physicaly atatch a RFID tag to a painting so we can check the correct one is in the correct case, without having to open it every time.

Now I understand that there are different kinds of RFID tags, some more secure than others.

Some are 128bit serial numbers. That doesn't sound much better than a barcode, and easy to copy and spoof.

Are there any other RFID tags which say have an internal counter and digitally sign the current count of reads? Or something like that?

**So I guess what would like to know is what should I be looking for (features, standards?) in RFID tags, which would indicate it is reasonably secure against copying?**

Comment: Are ,you looking for UHF RFID ? If so there have been recently addition to the standard in order to be able to have better security enforcement check the site that define those standards : https://www.gs1.fr/ . For others, you can also check the standard defined for GS1 and look for company that produce such tags.

Answer (score 1):

I've done work with class 1 gen 2 UHF tags in the past that regulated read/writes to memory with a password. Not sure how well (if) they protect against e.g. brute force but the understanding around our shop was that they're *reasonably* secure against tampering/cloning (although I'm not sure TIDs are as difficult to spoof as some would like to believe).

Like most everything though it depends greatly on your particular threat model.